# Запуск одной программы из другой.

Tags: c, visual-studio, c++, visual-c++

В ходе выполнения своей программы необходимо запустить другую и дождаться ее завершения. Делаю

```
WinExec("C:\\blabla.exe",1)
```

,но это не ждет. Как надо?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

А еще лучше воспользоваться функцией создания процесса

```
  TCHAR szPath[] = _T("C:\\blabla.exe");
  STARTUPINFO si;
  memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
  si.cb = sizeof(si);
  PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
  memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(pi));
  if ( CreateProcess(NULL, szPath, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi) )
  {
// программа запущена, ждем её завершения

    DWORD dwWait = WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    if ( dwWait == WAIT_OBJECT_0 )
    {
// программа благополучно завершилась

    }
    else if ( dwWait == WAIT_ABANDONED )
    {
// программа была насильно "прибита"

    }
//  else ну и может быть другие варианты ожидания

    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

Воспользуйтесь парой вызовов: `ShellExecuteEx(<SHELLEXECUTEINFO>)` для запуска процесса, и `WaitForSingleObject(<SHELLEXECUTEINFO>.hProcess, INFINITE)` для ожидания его завершения.
Пример (взят [отсюда](http://forum.wce.by/viewtopic.php?p=121630&sid=5be27141dc39a74dd18ae45611bda037#p121630) и немного доработан):

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO ExecInfo;

memset(&ExecInfo, 0, sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO));

ExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO); 
ExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS; 
ExecInfo.lpVerb = _T("open"); 
ExecInfo.lpFile = L"\\windows\\clog.lnk";

//Запуск процесса
if ( ShellExecuteEx(&ExecInfo) )
{
  //Ожидание завершения процесса
  WaitForSingleObject(ExecInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
}
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Просто

```
system("код команды");
```

**update** (см. мой комментарий к ответу(?) [[@zalipuha](/users/14917/zalipuha)](/users/14917/zalipuha) ниже)

Сделал `sh script` (просто быстрее и нагляднее), но для использования `system()` это не принципиально.

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ cat tttx.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define SCRIPT "bla bla.exe"
int 
main (int ac, char *av[]) 
{ 
  FILE *prog = fopen (SCRIPT, "w");
  fprintf (prog, "#!/bin/sh\necho А вот и запустили меня ... \\'$0\\'");
  fclose(prog);
  chmod(SCRIPT, 0755);
  char cmd[1024];
  sprintf (cmd, "'./%s'", SCRIPT);
  system(cmd);
  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc tttx.c
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out
А вот и запустили меня ... './bla bla.exe'
End
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

Вот как-то в таком духе. В винде не проверял (изучать тонкости cmd неохота).

Comment: к сожалению, если бы имя программы было «bla bla.exe», то она бы не исполнилась, так как в `system` передается `const char` который не может содержать пробел. Скажите, я прав? Просто в моем случае было именно так.Я был бы очень рад если бы было не так. **UPD** @avp, все таки я пришел к решению через `ShellExecute`, так как надо вышло, но параметр имени файла там тоже принимает тип данных `const char`, но в отличие от `system` не так капризен и без ругательств принимает `string` через `.c_str()`.

Comment: @zalipuha, в чем-то Вы правы (с пробелами возможны проблемы). Но только на в том, что cons char \* не может содержать пробел. Пробелов там может быть сколько угодно.

--

Проблема в том, что system() исполняет команду, запуская shell, передавая ему свой аргумент. Shell будет считать именем команды символы до первого пробела в этой строке и (если писать "в лоб"), то shell ругнется, что команды `bla` нет.

Примерчик, как с этим бороться я через пару минут  приведу в **update** своего ответа.